# Windows crashing when using Explorer to move ogg vorbis files

Tags: windows-10, ssd, windows-explorer, ogg

Explorer takes forever to move ogg vorbis files, then hangs and I have to do a hard restart.

My other file moving app works fine. I would prefer to use Explorer.

On my NVME SSD everything works fine.

They are both 70 - 80% full and about 1 1/2 and 1 year old.

Specs:

```
Ryzen 5 2600 (Planning to upgrade)
RTX 2070 Super
Asus B450-F Gaming 
SSD1: (Problem): Kingston A400 960GB 
SSD2: 500GB WD Blue SN550
```

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns and untick all NON Windows explorer extensions. In Options menu - Filter Options Hide Windows Entries then untick all that's left on Explorer tab. Does that fix it? If so reenable one by one

Comment: 70% full: Time to get a larger drive.